# How to max out bandwidth using concurrent requests?

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-multithreading, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to send approximately 6e6 post requests to a web server. Content is fetched only in the absence of a redirect status code.
The problem arises when traversing a stretch of data giving redirects; the bandwidth use is very low!(Like 10 % of the available bandwidth.)

I was using `multiprocessing.dummy` module first, then switched to using `asyncio` but even then, the requests don't utilize the whole bandwidth.

#### Note

Even though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318419/how-can-i-effectively-max-out-concurrent-http-requests) is exactly the problem, I don't understand Go , so , I asked here for a solution in Python.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831322/making-1-milion-requests-with-aiohttp-asyncio-literally?rq=1) is not the question I want to ask, I get around that problem by working with a subset of the data at a time.

Comment: Are you sure that site is going to actually reply to your flood of 6 million requests without throttling or blacklisting you?

Comment: @user2357112 No , the site is really, really dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, it may be even not connected with programming.
6e6 is really much, so it could be limited even because of poor network card.
The solution is to try stress-test utility to determine if your hardware could send that number of requests per second.
For example, use `ab` ApacheBench utility, like:
`ab -kc 6000000 -n 1000 http://your-site.com`

Comment: Yes 6e6 is very much , but i do it 1000-2000 requests at a time( I have tried tuning that number) Should i change 6e6 to this number in the question?

Comment: @AzharMehmood yes, 1000-2000 could be implemented in Python. To do so, you may need to utilize all the cores/CPUs of your machine, and a way of doing it is multiprocessing, but NOT with `multiprocessing.dummy` because it would spawn threads instead of processes and end up with GIL lock and usage of only one core. Use pure `multiprocessing`, or maybe `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` -- would be even simpler

Comment: So, processes , and not threads, OK. Can I do it with asyncio too? And would it be a wise choice? I am willing to use pypy to surpass GIL if it gives better results , since you are supposed to use threads for IO.

Comment: @AzharMehmood asyncio for processes, not exactly. First, asyncio runs tasks in event loop and event loop in thread and it's not thread-safe to access tasks from thread outside the event loop's own. But you could spawn processes with asyncio, to do so you need event loop to run in the main thread

Comment: @AzharMehmood if you like the asyncio paradigm, maybe you should look at Gevent framework (other common-used are Twisted and Tornado)